# My SQL #1064 Error (Query generated in CAKEPHP 3)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cakephp-3.0

Query generated by cakephp 3 but i got error #1064

```
INSERT INTO pows_watch_diagnosis (
  pows_lead_id, lead, created, modified, 
  id
) 
VALUES 
  (
    '1081d669-a4db-4c54-a33f-09bf674be46e', 
    'a:11:{s:5:"Bezel";a:5:{s:9:"Scratched";s:1:"1";s:6:"Dented";s:1:"0";s:6:"Broken";s:1:"0";s:11:"Discoloured";s:1:"0";s:16:"Luminous missing";s:1:"0";}s:5:"Glass";a:5:{s:9:"Scratched";s:1:"1";s:6:"Dented";s:1:"0";s:6:"Broken";s:1:"0";s:11:"Discoloured";s:1:"0";s:16:"Luminous missing";s:1:"0";}s:5:"Hands";a:5:{s:4:"Bent";s:1:"1";s:5:"Loose";s:1:"0";s:6:"Broken";s:1:"0";s:11:"Discoloured";s:1:"0";s:16:"Luminous missing";s:1:"0";}s:12:"Hour Markers";a:5:{s:9:"Scratched";s:1:"0";s:5:"Loose";s:1:"0";s:6:"Broken";s:1:"0";s:11:"Discoloured";s:1:"0";s:16:"Luminous missing";s:1:"0";}s:4:"Dial";a:5:{s:9:"Scratched";s:1:"0";s:5:"Loose";s:1:"0";s:6:"Broken";s:1:"0";s:11:"Discoloured";s:1:"0";s:16:"Luminous missing";s:1:"0";}s:5:"Crown";a:5:{s:9:"Scratched";s:1:"0";s:6:"Dented";s:1:"0";s:6:"Broken";s:1:"0";s:11:"Discoloured";s:1:"0";s:5:"Stuck";s:1:"0";}s:6:"Pusher";a:5:{s:9:"Scratched";s:1:"0";s:6:"Dented";s:1:"0";s:6:"Broken";s:1:"0";s:11:"Discoloured";s:1:"0";s:5:"Stuck";s:1:"0";}s:4:"Case";a:4:{s:9:"Scratched";s:1:"0";s:6:"Dented";s:1:"0";s:6:"Broken";s:1:"0";s:11:"Discoloured";s:1:"0";}s:9:"Case Back";a:5:{s:9:"Scratched";s:1:"0";s:6:"Dented";s:1:"0";s:6:"Broken";s:1:"0";s:11:"Discoloured";s:1:"0";s:7:"Missing";s:1:"0";}s:14:"Strap Bracelet";a:5:{s:9:"Scratched";s:1:"0";s:6:"Dented";s:1:"0";s:6:"Broken";s:1:"0";s:11:"Discoloured";s:1:"0";s:5:"Crack";s:1:"0";}s:12:"Clasp Buckle";a:5:{s:9:"Scratched";s:1:"0";s:6:"Dented";s:1:"0";s:6:"Broken";s:1:"0";s:11:"Discoloured";s:1:"0";s:7:"Missing";s:1:"0";}}', 
    '2023-07-26 10:53:17', '2023-07-26 10:53:17', 
    '8d556b20-c2a3-470d-895b-f701f5f3e60c'
  )
```

But i got Error Message

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lead, created, modified,
> id
> )
> VALUES
> (
> '1081d669-a4db-4c54-a33f-' at line 2

But I add `pows_lead_id`, `lead`, `created`, `modified`,
`id` in field name than query run fine.

Comment: Lead is a keyword in mysql